# Javafx how to access controls of second controller from first controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, getter-setter

I have one question regarding Javafx controller.
Lets say, I have multiple fxml files that are bind together in a main app. Then I have separate controllers for every fxml files. Lets see the following structure

```
com.par.app
  - MainApp.java   -> This is the main Application
  - FirstController.java 
  - SecondController.java

com.par.app.view
  - First.fxml
  - Second.fxml 

com.par.app.model
  - MyModel   -> This has some getter and setter methods.
```

Now as per above structure, I have a checkbox in First.fxml and a label in Second.fxml.

My Question : How can i set the label text in Second.FXML by checking and unchecking the checkbox in First.FXML , I have tried like this:

```
// In FirstController.Java
  1) Initialize the SecondController
  2) Get checkbox from FXMl as , priate CheckBox box1;
  3) On initialize(....) method, I have set the event handler, as box1.setOnAction(enableHandle)
  4) Finally the event Handler as,
  EventHandler<ActionEvent> enableHandle = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (box1.isSelected()) {

            secondController.setLabelText("PoP");
        } else {
            secondController.setText("Gone Wrong");
        }
    }
};

Similarly, On my second controller I have declared FXML control as, 
@FXML
private Label lblTes;

// the method
public void setLabelText(String a)
{
 this.lblTes.settest(a);
}
```

-> The above wont work as it returns Unknown Source.

The next way I tried is by using the  MyModel , and using getter and setter methods,  But unsuccessful.

I'm sorry my question is really long. I have tried but not succeeded.
What can I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
// my model looks like
public class MyModel {
   private String btnname;
   public String getBtnname() {
       return btnname;
   }
   public void setBtnname(String btnname) {
       this.btnname = btnname;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your comment don't make any sense, It rather explains what already did. Please read my question.

Comment: Using the model is the right way. You have to explain "unsuccessful"; what happened? Post code that shows how your controllers are both accessing a single model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the check box then in the controller of the FirstView (where you implement an event handler for the check box click) change the label text in your model.
Your model should be bound to your views therefore the label text in your SecondView should be updated.

If you did not bind the model to your views you may use an Observer pattern.

1.Change your model and extend java.util.Observable

```
public class MyModel extends Observable {
  private String btnname;
  public String getBtnname() {
    return btnname;
  }
  public void setBtnname(String btnname) {
    this.btnname = btnname;
    pingObservers()
  }
  private void pingObservers() {
   setChanged();
   notifyObservers();
  }
}
```

2. Register your SecondController as an Observer of the model.  When you set the model to the controller add a line similar to this:
   model.addObserver(this);
3. SecondController must implement java.util.Observer.update(...)
   void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
     // Set the label text with model value
   }
4. In you event handler in the FirstController when you call the setBtnname() method on your model the update() method in the SecondController will be called.  There up to you to add the code to change your label text.  Since the label is in the view controlled by SecondController you just need to inject a reference of the label in the controller with @FXML annotation.

Comment: if you read my last Lines then i have mentioned that I have tried using getter and setter methods, And I tried by calling the setter method on checkbox event, whereas on the SecondController i use getter method of the model to get the label. I think I am missing something here, Can you please illustrate your answer.

Comment: do not try to set the label text directly from the event handler. Instead update the model in the event handler. Then, either you bind the model to the view or you implement an Observer pattern to update the view in response to a model change.

Comment: Thanks your answer has helped a lot. Now I got the point what was missing . One more question, will a singleton pattern be an alternative to this observer pattern that you have suggested ?

Comment: Since this is a JavaFX project, I would recommend not using `Observable`, but using [JavaFX properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107) for the individual fields (e.g. `private final StringProperty btnname = new SimpleStringProperty();`). That way you can bind directly to the appropriate property in the model.